# Can't Verify identity of ''google.com'' on Asda or any other Cloud wifi Service

Tags: wireless-networking, cloud

Good Afternoon.

Ok so I'm hoping some of you techies have seen this out and about before.

You go to either Asda, Tesco, even Whetherspoons, you connect to their wifi service and when you go to google or any other site on your iphone a box pops up and says ''Cannot verify the identity of www.XXXXXX.com''.

I don't know a whole lot about how these wifi services work, or even certificates, could someone shed some light on why this happens?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your browser attempts to contact google.com, but instead it receives a response from a different domain. Normally, this would be suspicious because a website could impersonate another website, and potentially receive your login credentials. This is why your browser warns you about it. In this case, though, it is just your browser being redirected to the landing page for the public Wi-Fi service.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Cheers.